# Why was the central obstruction in Galileo's Solid State Imager (SSI) so large? Was the secondary mirror flat?

Tags: telescope, optical, galileo

According to Wikipedia's [Galileo Solid State Imager (SSI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_(spacecraft)#Solid_State_Imager_(SSI))

> The SSI was an 800-by-800-pixel solid state camera consisting of an array of silicon sensors called a charge-coupled device (CCD). Galileo was one of the first spacecraft to be equipped with a CCD camera.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> The optical portion of the camera was built as a Cassegrain telescope. Light was collected by the primary mirror and directed to a smaller secondary mirror that channeled it through a hole in the center of the primary mirror and onto the CCD.

Usually the secondary mirror of a Cassegrain is convex and a small fraction of the diameter of the primary. In the photo however, the central obstruction appears to be **about 60% of the diameter of the entrance aperture**, which is roughly how big a *flat secondary mirror* would have to be to "(channel the light) through a hole in the center of the primary mirror and onto the CCD."

**Question:** Why was the central obstruction in Galileo's Solid State Imager (SSI) so large? Was the secondary mirror flat?

[image: Galileo Solid State Imager (SSI)] [image: [Galileo Solid State Imager (SSI) zoom/crop]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I think we are looking at the [aperture cover](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/experiment/display.action?id=1989-084B-10).  In the picture below I've pointed out what looks like hinges (top) and a latch (bottom).

[image]

There's a cutaway of the scope here which does not show such a large obstruction.

[image]

Source: https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/114747/Carlton%20Extended%20Abstract_Submitted_v2.pdf?sequence=1

This next image appears to confirm that it's a cover.

[image]

Image from here https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4231/chapter5.pdf

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what "deployable aperture cover" means exactly? What might happens when one deploys it?

Comment: I would bet that those hinges are spring loaded and it flips up when the latch is released.

Comment: I see, so perhaps the "quartz clear aperture" is there so that if the cover fails to deploy it still works as a telescope?

Comment: Sounds like a suspenders-and-belt approach, very typical!